# Is there a way to make assertions based on tags in junit5?

Tags: junit5

I have a testing system based on JUnit 4 that enforces testing policies based on some custom annotations.  In particular, I can annotate methods and have the testing system enforce timeouts and resource access from those methods.

For example, tests annotated with @Medium must complete in less than sixty seconds, and cannot access the network.

Tests lacking a custom annotation are categorized as "small" tests, and must complete in less than 10 seconds, and cannot access the network or filesystem (e.g. making sure unit tests actually are unit tests).

The test system also ensures all small tests pass before attempting any medium tests.  All medium tests must pass before attempting any large tests, etc.

Implementing this on top of JUnit 4 was fairly straightforward, and only required customizing a few key parts of the system.

I'm exploring migrating this to JUnit 5, and I wanted to find out if there's a good way to do this.  The new discovery and filtering mechanisms will really simplify the test ordering, but with the removal of runners, I'm not sure how to enforce the test sizing policy.

Note: having the tests themselves enforce the policy won't work, because I need to make sure tests written with no knowledge of the testing system have the small test policy enforced.

I believe I could create a custom test engine, but I think that might be a bit overkill.

Comment: How did you ensure that a test does not access network or file system?

Comment: I created a custom SecurityManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a custom `TestEngine` would be overkill for this purpose.

As for accessing *tags*, that's easy via any extension that you implement. Extension callback methods receive access to the `ExtensionContext` (or subclass thereof) which provides access to the tags. See `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getTags()`.

> I'm not sure how to enforce the test sizing policy.

That's the one part that is currently (as of JUnit Jupiter 5.0 M3) not possible, but we plan to make such things possible, hopefully before 5.0 GA. See [issue 157](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/157) for details.

Comment: So, in summary: No, there is not presently an easy way to do this, but it will hopefully be in Jupiter 5.0 M5, using whatever executor extension mechanism the JUnit 5 team decides on.